# How to get the sum of Fibonacci sequence 0 to less than 500

Tags: java

The question goes like this Write a program to find the Fibonacci sequence from 0 to less than a 500. Then display the sum of all the sequences.
The sequence goes as follows:

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377
```

with a total sum of **986**.

**Here is my code:**

```
public class Fibonacci {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 500, t1 = 0, t2 = 1;
        while (t1 <= n)
        {
            System.out.print(t1 + " , ");
            int sum = t1 + t2;
            t1 = t2;
            t2 = sum;
            sum = t1 + t2;
            }
             System.out.println("");System.out.println("Sum: "+(t2-1));
        }
    }
```

To get a total sum of **986** what confuses me is I do get **987** if I haven't deducted **1**.

Comment: Here's a hint: 1+1 = 2 = 3-1; 1+1+2 = 4 = 5-1; 1+1+2+3 = 7 = 8-1; 1+1+2+3+5 = 12 = 13-1... do you see a pattern?

Comment: Think carefully about the intended function of each variable in your program, then ask yourself whether what you're doing actually makes sense. Is there a specific variable in your program that's intended to hold the sum? If so, what is the procedure you intend to follow for ensuring that it holds the sum? Now, is the code actually following that procedure? And is that the variable that you use for your final output?

Comment: Hi guys thankyou for reminding, I'll keep that in mind and I'll make sure that next time I won't take shortcuts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should create a new variable that holds your sum which initially starts at 0, your code is summing using t2 which is declared as 1, that's why you are having a +1 in your total, this code should work fine:

```
 public static void main(String []args){

 int n = 500, t1 = 0, t2 = 1;
 int total=0; 
 
    while (t1 <= n)
    {
        total+=t1;
        System.out.print(t1 + " , ");
        int sum = t1 + t2;
        t1 = t2;
        t2 = sum;
        sum = t1 + t2;
     }
        
     System.out.println("");System.out.println("Sum: "+(total));
 }
```

Comment: Thankyou YOUSFI Mohammed Walid, I see I forgot to put a variable in my program very much appreciated.